# C# - TagLib Get ISO chunk offset values

Tags: c#, mp4, taglib, taglib-sharp

So I'm working with TagLib trying to extract the ChunkOffset values.

I've gotten this far with the code. And the way I'm doing it is definitely wrong.

```
TagLib.File f = new TagLib.Mpeg4.File("C:\\file.mp4");

//Code from here
TagLib.Mpeg4.BoxHeader Box = new TagLib.Mpeg4.BoxHeader();
TagLib.Mpeg4.IsoHandlerBox Handle = new TagLib.Mpeg4.IsoHandlerBox(Box, f, *what goes here??* );
//To here is quite obviously wrong

TagLib.Mpeg4.IsoChunkOffsetBox offsetbox = new TagLib.Mpeg4.IsoChunkOffsetBox(Box, f, Handle);   
uint[] array = offsetbox.Offsets;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried editing [BmffViewer](https://github.com/jeremypoulter/basemedia/tree/master/BMFF/BmffViewer) to achieve this task and it worked. No luck with TagLib though.